# How to allow place picture for highest rank?

Tags: php

so I am trying to figure out a way with php to say if a users rank is the highest, then put a picture next to their name. I can do it for a specific user but I am not sure how to do it for the highest rank

```
<td> 
<?php if($r->rank=='3') {
    echo '<img src="image.jpg">';
}?>
</td>
```

Comment: So you want to determine what user has the highest rank in comparison to all of the other users?

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP well I already have a script that puts the person with the highest rank at the top of the page, but because the rank keeps changing, I need a way to just say "highest" rank

Comment: add a "highestRank" property to your `$r` and use that

Comment: @rc I am not exactly sure how to do this though

Comment: @rc IT would be something like this i'm guessing $highest = 
    if($r->rank==$highest)

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you have to determine what the highest rank is so it will start like 
I'm assuming you want one star per user thats on the page or something of sorts

```
 $star_given = false;

 foreach($foo as $bar) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo ($star_given===false ? $bar->rank >= 3 ? : "<div style='background: url(img/foo.png) no-repeat' : "&nbsp;");
   echo "</td> 
}
```

This is not catering for if more than one person has the highest rating though e.g

```
$personA->rank = 3;
$personB->rank = 2;
$personC->rank = 3;
```

in this case you would just remove the `$star_given` property and just let it check for the rank

### **edit**

---

Sorry seem to have to misunderstood your question;

You would simply add a variable called 
   `$highest_rating=0;`
Before the loop. Then when someone becomes the highest rating you simply go like `$highest_rating = $r->rank`. Then after the Loop you can echo the highest Rating , or alternitavly you can use JS for this.
Here is a small script showing you how to access tables
[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/tucesaxe/2/edit?html,js)

Comment: the problem is that the highest rank isn't just a set number and can constantly change

Comment: Is there a certain highest rank though ? \n like the maximum rank could only unless you use a combination of PHP and Javascript to find the user that has the highest rank.

I'm also not shure if the rank should be something other than a **number** though. Please explain more , Like what are the variations of the *highest_rank*

Comment: No, there is no certain highest rank. I am not exactualy sure how it could be done, because it would have to be something like highest_rank= top

Comment: Right now this is what I have, and it displays an image for anyone who has a point or rank    <td> <?php 
    $highest_rating=0;
    if($highest_rating = $r->rank) {
    echo '<img src="006_dgLjq8N.jpg">';
    }?></td>

Comment: That is not going to do anything though like `$highest_rating = 0;` so the first person that goes into the loop that has a `$rating >= 0` then they will have a image next to them, And if someone with a greater rating comes in they will **also** have a image next to them, I think the best way to achieve this would be too sort the Data first then use good old JS to add a star to the first person on the table ;)

Comment: That's the problem, I am not sure of a way to make that functionality

Comment: Has any of this helped you with a solution?

Comment: Could you post your current code then i can figure that out ?